# Table hover in CSS doesn't work properly

Tags: css, html-table, hover

I have table with two row, one row has class another has no class.
I want add hover property to my table but it just work on row without class.
what should I do?

```css
.datagrid table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.datagrid {
  font: normal 12px/150% B Yekan;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #36752D;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.datagrid table td,
.datagrid table th {
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
.datagrid table thead th {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #36752D), color-stop(1, #275420));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #36752D 5%, #275420 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#36752D', endColorstr='#275420');
  background-color: #36752D;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-left: 1px solid #36752D;
}
.datagrid table tbody td {
  color: #275420;
  border-left: 1px solid #C6FFC2;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.datagrid table tbody .alt td {
  background: #DFFFDE;
  color: #275420;
}
.datagrid table tbody td:first-child {
  width: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}
.datagrid table tbody td:last-child {
  width: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}
.datagrid table tbody tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.datagrid table tfoot td div {
  border-top: 1px solid #36752D;
  background: #DFFFDE;
}
.datagrid table tfoot td {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px
}
.datagrid table tfoot td div {
  padding: 2px;
}
.datagrid table tfoot input {
  font-weight: bolder;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #36752D;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #36752D), color-stop(1, #275420));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #36752D 5%, #275420 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#36752D', endColorstr='#275420');
  background-color: #36752D;
}
.datagrid table tbody tr:hover {
  background: #FFF380;
}
.datagrid table tbody .alt:hover {
  background: #FFF380;
}
```

```html
<div class="datagrid">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center;width: 10%;">row</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;width: 20%;">date</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;width:10%;">correct</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;width: 10%;">wront</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;width: 10%;">blank</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;width: 10%;">score</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;width: 30%;">detail</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="alt">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>das</td>
        <td>correct</td>
        <td>wrong</td>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>score</td>
        <td><a href "#">page<a></td>
</tr>    
<tr>
 <td>1</td><td>das</td><td>correct</td>
    <td>wrong</td><td>blank</td>
    <td>score</td>
    <td><a href"#">page<a></td>
</tr> 
</tbody>
</table></div>
```

Comment: you've given `background` to the `<td>` and and changing `background` of `<tr>` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code

```
  .datagrid table tbody .alt:hover td {
        background: #fff380 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    }
```

Instead of

```
.datagrid table tbody .alt:hover {
  background: #FFF380;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your tr background is actually getting changed, but you have defined a background color for the td in the tr... because of that, you can't see the changed color! :)

```css
.datagrid table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.datagrid {
  font: normal 12px/150% B Yekan;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #36752D;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.datagrid table td,
.datagrid table th {
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
.datagrid table thead th {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #36752D), color-stop(1, #275420));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #36752D 5%, #275420 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#36752D', endColorstr='#275420');
  background-color: #36752D;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-left: 1px solid #36752D;
}
.datagrid table tbody td {
  color: #275420;
  border-left: 1px solid #C6FFC2;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.datagrid table tbody .alt {
  background: #DFFFDE;
  color: #275420;
}
.datagrid table tbody td:first-child {
  width: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}
.datagrid table tbody td:last-child {
  width: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}
.datagrid table tbody tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.datagrid table tfoot td div {
  border-top: 1px solid #36752D;
  background: #DFFFDE;
}
.datagrid table tfoot td {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px
}
.datagrid table tfoot td div {
  padding: 2px;
}
.datagrid table tfoot input {
  font-weight: bolder;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #36752D;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #36752D), color-stop(1, #275420));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #36752D 5%, #275420 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#36752D', endColorstr='#275420');
  background-color: #36752D;
}
.datagrid table tbody tr:hover {
  background: #FFF380;
}
.datagrid table tbody .alt:hover {
  background: #FFF380;
}
```

```html
<div class="datagrid">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center;width: 10%;">row</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;width: 20%;">date</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;width:10%;">correct</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;width: 10%;">wront</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;width: 10%;">blank</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;width: 10%;">score</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;width: 30%;">detail</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="alt">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>das</td>
        <td>correct</td>
        <td>wrong</td>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>score</td>
        <td><a href "#">page<a></td>
</tr>    
<tr>
 <td>1</td><td>das</td><td>correct</td>
    <td>wrong</td><td>blank</td>
    <td>score</td>
    <td><a href"#">page<a></td>
</tr> 
</tbody>
</table></div>
```

that code should work... ijust removed the styling from the `tr td` and changed it to just the `td`

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the background color to the td like this:

```
.datagrid table tbody .alt:hover td {
  background: #FFF380!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this quite easily with CSS!

This is actually a really simple problem, but I'll explain it with a bit of detail for you.

You have your table row setup with background-colors, as do your table cells. So if you were to hover over a table row, that would change the table row's background-color, leaving the table cell's background color the same. This is why you aren't seeing any changes happening.

You can go about this in two ways:

1. Set the background-color of your table cells to "transparent" and allow the background-color of the row to come forward.

   2. (This method's the best if your table cells are multiple colors), setup your table row's hover class like this:

.datagrid tr:hover td
{
    background-color:#``f2e8da;
}
 With your style rule setup like this, when the table row's hovered over, it will effect its child cells color!

Answer (score 0):

That also work fine for me :

```
  .table-hover tbody tr:hover td {
        background: #f9f9f9;
    }
```